# ExhaustiveTemplateMatching Rectangle doesn't work when there is more than one template on image

Tags: c#, aforge, template-matching, accord.net

I've been working on my project that involves Exhaustive Template Matching using C# and AForge.net. I've managed to build application that finds templates. Well, almost. It works perfectly when there is only one template on image. However, when I tries to search for one template when there is multiple of them on image, it does find them all (I know that thanks to MessageBox and foreach loop), but rectangle always shows only one. How can I fix that?

Here's the code:

```
Bitmap Temp= new Bitmap(textBox2.Text);
Grayscale OW = new GrayscaleBT709();
Bitmap Template = OW.Apply(Temp);

ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0.8f);

Bitmap Image = new Bitmap(textBox1.Text);
Bitmap GrayImage = OW.Apply(Image);

{
    TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage(GrayImage, Template);

    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Image);

    if (matchings[0].Similarity > 0.8f)
    {
        foreach (TemplateMatch m in matchings)
        {
            int X = matchings[0].Rectangle.X;
            int Y = matchings[0].Rectangle.Y;

            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 3), X, Y, matchings[0].Rectangle.Width, matchings[0].Rectangle.Height);
            ShowResult.Image = Image;
            MessageBox.Show("Match found!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your *foreach* loop, you should use your *m* variable instead of *matchings[0]*. *matchings[0]* represent the first item in your list, so you're always drawing the same (first) match.